# Is there a command to change path from current location to default directory, in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Is there a command to change the current directory to default directory? (I'm not asking about permanently changing the default directory, here!)

For example, if the current directory is "..\xyz" and my default command prompt directory is D:\Abc, is there a way to navigate directly to D:\Abc (without giving >cd D:\Abc)?

Comment: There is a great answer here.. http://superuser.com/a/699052/33955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option built into `cd` to do this but you could certainly create a `.cmd` script file that does it.  For example, you could put this into a `home.cmd` file somewhere on your search `PATH` and go to `D:\Abc` just by typing `home`:

```
@ echo off
cd /D D:\Abc
```

Comment: Or `call home` in batch files ;)

Comment: Might I point out the security risk? - I can just add malicious code to your batch file or even have a similar named file earlier in the PATH and you wouldn't have an idea. Having batch files available in path is so wrong for security.

Comment: There's nothing special about scripts.  You could have the same problem with malicious code in an .exe earlier in your PATH and you also wouldn't have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

There's no in-built command, but why not create your own, for example **dd (Default Directory)**? Just save the following command in a batch/script file in any location, say **C:\Macros.bat** or **C:\Macros.cmd**:

```
@doskey dd=cd /d D:\Abc
```

Now in the registry (**Regedit.exe**) navigate to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

Create a string value (REG_SZ) or expandable string value (REG_EXPAND_SZ) called **AutoRun** and set it to **C:\Macros.bat** (or .cmd as the case may be).

The same **AutoRun** value can also be added to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`

Any commands specified in the HKLM AutoRun value will run before those in the HKCU counterpart. See `cmd /?` for more.

Now whenever you open a cmd.exe instance/window, Macros.bat (or .cmd) will be executed automatically and the DOSKey command alias will be (re)created as a result. So you can simply type your new command **dd** to jump to the specified default directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd %HOMEPATH%
```

Although creating a batch file as Nicole mentions is probably easier.

Comment: though on my computer cmd.exe defaults to c:\windows\system32  for some reason, regardless of the fact that %HOMEPATH% is the user profile.

Comment: @barlop Are you running cmd from a shortcut, the file directly, or from the run dialog?

Comment: @DavidRuhmann start..run..cmd<ENTER> on xp. But looks like I might've found what makes the difference. In the registry   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor    Having a Key called Autorun, with no value.  Try that. And see if yours goes to c:\windows\system32  It might be that you don't have the key at all. For example, if I rename the key to autorunn(like no autorun key at all no doubt) then the cmd prompt goes to %homepath%. If the key is called Autorun with no value, then it goes to c:\windows\system32

Comment: On a related note.  In Windows 7 if you run cmd with administrative privileges it goes to c:\windows\system32 as well though I haven't checked if that's related to administrator on my comp anyway not having a profile as i haven't tried logging in as that. but i doubt it's because of that, as i've heard that in win7, unlike xp. runas administrator sticks to the same profile, which (in my case anyway) has administrative privileges, and just elevates the process to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your command line started out in `D:\Abc` and you only need to be in `..\xyz` for a few commands, use the `pushd` and `popd` commands.  Here is a batch script example:

```
@echo off
echo.Im at this directory: %CD%
pushd "..\xyz"
echo.Im now at this directory: %CD%
popd
echo.Im back at this directory: %CD%
pause
```

Otherwise you will need to use the `cd` command to change the current directory. This only works for a batch script.

```
@echo off
echo.Im at this directory: %CD%
cd "..\xyz"
echo.Im now at this directory: %CD%
cd "%~dp0"
echo.Im back at this directory: %CD%
pause
```

Note that "%~dp0" will take you back to the original directory in which the batch script started.

Comment: Note that a in batch file located in directory A, but executed from directory B, `%~dp0` will point to directory A, not necessarily the starting directory.

Comment: @MarcksThomas  That is correct, I tried to make that point with my last note in the answer, I guess it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is a universal command to create the "home" command tool on any Windows machine.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and enter the following command:

```
CMD /C ((SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION &ECHO ^@ECHO OFF &ECHO ECHO Changing to "home" directory... 1^>CON&ECHO CD /D %%USERPROFILE%%)1>"%SYSTEMROOT%\home.cmd")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the game but I would like to post my solution for anybody that stumbles across this question (Like me). I created a simple how-to that nobody else has mentioned and it's easier and more direct IMO. 
Check it out:
[Spiceworks - Change Default Directory](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/123751-change-the-default-path-in-the-command-prompt)

1. Open the Command Prompt's Location.

   On the start screen / menu, type in "cmd", right-click it and select "Open File Location".
2. Open the Command Prompt Properties and change the "Start In" Property.

   Right-click on the "Command Prompt" icon, select "Properties", and edit the "Start In" property to your desired path.