# How to set an alias in Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I used to work on bash and benefit a lot from alias. Is there any equivalent way in Windows Command Line?

I don't want to simulate a Linux environment, so cygwin is not a choice. I just need some shortcut for some very long command, like `cd a_very_long_path`.

Comment: You would use `doskey` (don't be fooled by the name it is not the old MS DOS doskey). Use `doskey /?` for more information. Other than that, I'm afraid, this question is off topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a command to change path from current location to default directory, in Windows command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/519223/is-there-a-command-to-change-path-from-current-location-to-default-directory-in) Specifically, see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/519601/138343) to know how you can have your DOSKey macros be auto-loaded when the Command Prompt is opened.

Comment: related + a way to make doskey permanent http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp#comment178413_49194

Answer (score 118, accepted):

As Christian.K said in his comment, the DOSKEY command can be used to define macros, which are  analogous to aliases.

```
doskey macroName=macroDefinition
```

Macro parameters are referenced in the definition via `$` prefixed positions: `$1` through `$9` and `$*` for all.

See the [doskey technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx), or type `doskey /?` or `help doskey` from the command line for more information.

But there are serious limitations with DOSKEY macros:

- The macros only work on the interactive command line - they do not work within a batch script.
- They cannot be used on either side of a pipe: Both `someMacro|findstr '^'` and `dir|someMacro` fail.
- They cannot be used within a FOR /F commands: `for /f %A in ('someMacro') do ...` fails

The limitations are so severe that I rarely use DOSKEY macros.

Obviously you can create batch scripts instead of macros, and make sure the script locations are in your PATH. But then you must prefix each script with CALL if you want to use the script within another script.

You could create simple variable "macros" for long and oft used commands, but syntax is a bit awkward to type, since you need to expand the "macro" when you want to use it.

Definition:

```
set "cdMe=cd a_very_long_path"
```

Usage (from command line or script)

```
%cdMe%
```

Comment: Thanks, then is there any way to work within a batch script?

Comment: @JermaineXu - No way with DOSKEY macros. See my updated answer for crude alternatives.

Comment: The pro of the second solution is that, piping will work. The first solution with doskey will not work when you want to use the macro in piping.

Comment: ?how can I put this macros visible to the Win+R box (Run dialog)

Comment: @ZEE - You can't. DOSKEY macros must be physically keyed into a console window that is running cmd.exe.

Comment: Please check this link , this should take care of long path issue https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Windows_file_paths_longer_than_255_characters.

Comment: @dbenham Still Can you show an example of running a cmd.exe  with an alias ?

Comment: This might be worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/422845

Comment: It works in the current cmd terminal when I use : doskey macroName=macroDefinition , but didn't work in another instance of cmd , can't we store it globally so that it can be accessed via all terminal?

Answer (score 37):

You can make a batch script and save it into your path.

Add `%USERPROFILE%\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable. Then save your scripts in there.

`quickcd.cmd`

```
@echo off
cd /d a_very_long_path
```

Now you can type `quickcd` at the command line.

It can also be called inside a script using the `call` function

```
call quickcd
```

Comment: This doesn't work - setting the directory within a batch file only affects the batch file. The path reverts when the batch file exits.

Comment: It's working for me. `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648]`

Comment: That's really strange. So if you copy and paste the above example (changing the directory to one that exists) it works for you?

Comment: Is your folder on another drive? You might need to add the `/d` flag to `CD`

Answer (score 23):

`subst`

If you're really trying to get around something like this:

```
C:> cd \users\myLoginID\documents\clients\MTV\strategy\roadmap\deliverable\final
```

You can use the `subst` command to map that long path to a separate drive letter

```
subst m: c:\users\myLoginID\documents\clients\MTV\strategy\roadmap\deliverable\final
```

Then, when you want to jump into that folder, you can just type `m:` at the command line.

The advantage of this over `doskey` is that it works in all batch programs, and shows up in any file dialog box within Windows.

If you don't want the mapping any more:

```
subst m: /D
```

Comment: I also like this but it DOES eat up drive letters.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the same trick, that windows uses:
set an environment-variable (or just a variable in a batch-context)
for example there is an environment-variable %windir% (and some others)
So you can do an

```
cd C:\Windows\
```

or

```
cd %windir%
```

which does the same.
So all, you have to do is:

```
set "mydir=C:\very\long\path\to\my\data\"
```

after that you can do (from whereever you are):

```
dir %mydir%
```

or

```
cd %mydir%
```

or whatever you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **doskey.exe**, here is an example:

```
doskey qcd=cd [pathname]
```

And now if you type `qcd` then it will **cd** to that path.

Here is some help with **doskey** macro's:

```
doskey [macroname]=[command]
```

That is the simplest form, here is an example:

```
doskey word=echo This is a really, really long sentence.
```

and if you type `word` the output is:

> This is a really, really long sentence.

You can use $1-$9 for parameters, here is an example:

```
doskey npd=notepad $1
```

and if you type `npd` it will open **notepad** but if we type `npd test.txt` it will open **test.txt** in **notepad**.

You can use $* for all parameters, here is another example:

```
doskey prt=echo $*
```

and if you type `prt This is short.` then the output will be:

> This is short.

You can use $T for multiple commands, here is an example:

```
doskey newline=echo $1 $T echo $2
```

and if you type `newline Hello and` then the output will be:

> Hello
>
> and

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an "alias" like that specifically for changing directory. Basically I created a file named `fav.bat` and put it into a folder in PATH (e.g C:\MyBatches):

```
@setlocal
@echo off
set userChoice=%1
rem The format is:
rem call :condition SHORTCUT FOLDER
call :condition web c:\Git\SecThor\SecWeb\App\
call :condition cloud c:\Git\SecThor\SecCloud\dojo.backend\
call :condition good c:\Users\Vitaly\Dropbox\Projects\goodread-friends\
endlocal
popd
GOTO :eof

:condition
rem We do PUSHD twice since endlocal does popd once :|
if "%userChoice%"=="%1" pushd %2 & pushd %2 & echo pushd %2
if "%userChoice%"=="" echo %1 =^> %2
GOTO :eof
```

Then I can jump to any predefined folder very quickly. I wrote a full article about that technique [here](https://medium.com/@vitalyb/favorite-folders-in-command-line-421772cdab5f).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but was still #2 result when googling this issue before I found a fix so I'll share my solution.

1. Create a folder for your scripts `C:\shell-scripts`
2. Add created folder to `PATH`
3. Inside that folder, create a `alias.cmd` and/or `alias.ps1` (depending on if you use CMD or PowerShell)
4. Contents of file:

   - ```
     pushd "C:\some\path\here"
     ```
5. Make sure you close and re-open your terminal to load PATH
6. Run `alias`

Note on my machine I was able to make both a `.cmd` and a `.ps1` file with the same name without conflicts so I can use the alias in either PowerShell or CMD.

Comment: Thanks for this but for every alias should I be creating a separate .cmd / .ps1 file? Isn't there a "shortcut" for this?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you remain on the same drive, i.e. no `D:` then `cd D:\somedir\` needed.

In my case, **C:** holds system files, but all work is on **D:**

2 parts.  first set some working directories, using a batch file.

let's say **localprofile.cmd**.  You can have multiple ones of these, just run them as needed.

```
set wd1=D:\home\work\fb440.dumper
set wd2=D:\home\work\py\tests
```

now use another command file to move around, based on those environment variables you just set.

**wd.cmd**

```
echo off
d:
if %1.==. set | findstr wd
if %1==1 cd %wd1%
if %1==2 cd %wd2%
if %1==3 cd %wd3%
if %1==4 cd %wd4%
if %1==5 cd %wd5%
if %1==6 cd %wd6%
```

And a bit of a sample use:

```
D:\home\bin>wd 2

D:\home\bin>echo off
D:\home\work\py\tests>wd 1

D:\home\work\py\tests>echo off
```

wd by itself is supposed to show me the list of bookmarked directories.  It works, but not sure why I am getting this "unexpected cd" message.

```
D:\home\work\fb440.dumper>wd

D:\home\work\fb440.dumper>echo off
wd1=D:\home\work\fb440.dumper
wd2=D:\home\work\py\tests
cd was unexpected at this time.

D:\home\work\fb440.dumper>
```

Regular .cmd batches

Aside from directory navigation, you can create a **foo.cmd** somewhere on your PATH and it can act much as an alias.  Remember, unlike Linux/OSX shells, cmd files can affect environment variables and the session, without needing to *source* them.

I have a **cdbin.cmd** to navigate me, for example:

```
d:
cd \home\bin
```

And this is a pseudo-grep **grep.cmd**

```
findstr -n %1 %2
```

in action (whatever sort /+2 /+10 means)

`D:\home\work\fb440.dumper>grep class *.py | sort /+2 /+10`

```
dumper2.py:18:class PrettySafeLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):            
dumper2.py:27:class Comparator(object):                           
dumper2.py:3:class module_settings:                               
linker2.py:5:class module_settings:                               
dumper2.py:65:class DataCompProcessor(object):                    
dumper2.py:69:class DataCompTextRenderer(DataCompProcessor):      
dumper2.py:76:class DataComparator(object):
```